# Using HTACCESS for Secret Access

Tags: security, htaccess

I saw this post yesterday http://digwp.com/2011/01/simpler-login-url/ where a 'custom' word is used to direct the user from `url.com/admin` to `url.com/wp-login`.php and I'm asking (also did so in the comments without an answer) if its possible to **deny any access** to the admin **unless used a secret url**, so if a user is not logged in and tries `url.com/wp-admin` or `wp-login.php` he's denied access and only if he tries `url.com/my-secret` he's then redirected to the admin?

thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible using .htaccess alone.

Even if it were, what would be the usefulness of keeping a secret which would be displayed in plain text in the URL bar?

Comment: it will be only known to the editor/admin of the site, it's a secret as in a special 'keyword' just to get to door.